# Compare elements by Linked Server rules for values (MSSQL+ Linked MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, optimization

I'll try to briefly describe problem.
I have (to simplify) 2 servers (MSSQL and MYSQL) with students data inside and system grades table.

I am trying to compare GRADE AND Expected (grade) on one query for each student, as described below

Sudents table (MS SQL)

+----------+----------+-------------+
| Student | GRADE | Expected |
+----------+----------+-------------+
| Mike      |      A      |       A       |
+----------+----------+-------------+
| Frank    |     C      |       B        |
+----------+----------+-------------+

Grades Tabele (MySQL)

+-------+-----+
| Grade | Val |
+-------+-----+
|   A     |   6   |
+-------+-----+
|   B     |   5   |
+-------+-----+
|   C     |   4   |
+-------+-----+

Expected result:

+----------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| Student | GRADE | Expected | Achievement  |
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| Mike      |      A      |        A       |   On target     |
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| Frank    |      C      |        B       |  Below Targ   |
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------------+

query idea (sketch):

SELECT Student, GRADE, Expected
  CASE ((SELECT * FROM openquery(MYSQL,'SELECT Val WHERE Grade=GRADE'))>(SELECT * FROM openquery(MYSQL,'SELECT Val WHERE Grade=Expected')))
   THAN 'Above Targ'
    ELSE 
     CASE ((SELECT * FROM openquery(MYSQL,'SELECT Val WHERE Grade=GRADE'))<(SELECT * FROM openquery(MYSQL,'SELECT Val WHERE Grade=Expected')))
      THAN 'Below Targ'
      ELSE 'On target'
      END
    END AS Achievement
 FROM Students

I am not sure, I suspect, after research, that it is not possible to pass
 parameter (GRADE or Expected), but hope that someone
 may worked that out and may advise some way to achieve that.

Basically the question is: How to get this comparison working?

What would be the best way?

I have roughly 3k students to get (here simplified) result.

Alternative is to process this comparison in PHP, but this would requie another connection, extra query and loop over all students.

I think that single query (with comparison) would be more efficient (and definitely more challenging ;) )

Thanks for help in advance.

(Sorry for my poor editor's skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL query:

```
select t.student,
     t.grade,
     t.expected,
     case 
        when m.val > m1.val then 'Above Target'
        when m.val < m1.val then 'Below target'
        else 'on target'
        end as achievements
     from students t
left join (select * from openquery(mysql, 'select * from Grade')) m on t.grade = m.grade
left join (select * from openquery(mysql, 'select * from Grade')) m1 on t.expected = m1.grade
```